# Aligned images in div responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code for a section on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/qda6bkze/

The problem is, I can't get it to be responsive. Ideally, I'd like for the orange box and the picture to align themselves so that the picture overlaps the orange box. Something like this: http://puu.sh/bMb8M.jpg

I know I'll have to use media queries, but I was wondering what changes to make in order for the image to align itself under the orange block, since right now it sits to the right no matter how big the browser window is.

Here's what i have for CSS now:

```
.home-feature4 {
position:relative;
max-width:1200px;
}
#boxy {
width:1200px;
height:790px;
}
.feature4text, .orangeblock, .orangephoto {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
}
.feature4text {
z-index: 2;
color:#32719a;
font-family:"Scout", sans-serif; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
font-size:12pt;
top: 100px;
left: 120px;
width:425px; 
}
.orangeblock {
z-index:1;
top: 280px;
left: 20px;
}
.orangephoto {
z-index: 3;
top: 0px;
left: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that you have the position set to absolute, which takes it out of the flow of the document, so it doesn't react to resizing.

Comment: z-index will not work without giving it a position of absolute, fixed, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `top` and `left` properties and add `float: left;`
Like so:

```
.orangephoto {
   z-index: 3;
   float: left;
}
```

[A reference for the float property (and others) from W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your div an "ID" and place the image inside the div. I wrote some mark up for you below feel free to copy it and make adjustments for it to work on your site. Let me know if you have any further questions I would be happy to help.

```css
/* Your can adjust the CSS however you see fit for your Project */
#orangeblock {
 width:410px; /* Give your background block extra pixels needed for your border */
 height:310px; /* Same with your height */
 background-color:#CCC;
}
#orangeblock img {
 width: 390px; /* your image size shouls always be smaller than your div size */
 height: 290px; /* This will allow you to see the background image */
 padding: 10px; /* Your padding will have to be adjusted to get the image where your want */
 
 /* you can also use padding-left: padding-right: padding-top: padding-bottom: and place whatever pixels you like */
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="orangeblock">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0636/3475/files/home-ossection-04-photo.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```